# if localstorage empty show welcome message

Tags: javascript, local-storage

I am trying to write a simple function that checks the length of the localstorage, if it is 0, undefined, or null, I would like the user to see a pop up message since that means they are a first time visitor, or show them a button to trigger the message if they had come previously.

However I cannot even get the browser to tell me what value is being passed into localstorage.

Here is my code:

```
function local() {
var storageLocal = window.localStorage.length;

if (storageLocal !== 0 && storageLocal === undefined && storageLocal === null ){

document.getElementById('message').style.cssText = 'display: block';

}

else {
document.getElementById('button').style.cssText = 'display: block';
}

}
```

Here is my css:

```
#message, #button {display: none;}
```

HTML:

```
<div id="message">MESSAGE</div>

<div id="button">BUTTON</div>
```

Please let me know if there is an easier way to do this. I am implementing into a CMS program and therefore cannot use "append to" jquery.

Comment: You've defined your function `local` but where is it being called?

Comment: You are not using the methods to make this. When you use localStorage, you need to pass a key/value pair to store something. Your code is testing if localStorage is available, but not if it's filled with data.

Comment: `localStorage.length` will never be `undefined` or `null`.

Comment: And certainly never `undefined` and `null` at the same time, which the condition checks for.

Comment: Thank you! I am placing the function in the head so wont it fire on page load?

Answer (score 0):

Based on my understanding, I find a problem in your condition.

`window.localStorage.length` will return a number. Hence, you should only check for number. Additionally, you want to show the message in case the length is 0, hence, you need to check for equality.

Hence, you need to update your condition

from

```
if (storageLocal !== 0 && storageLocal === undefined && storageLocal === null ){
```

to

```
if (storageLocal === 0){
```